# How to send several String to Spring?

Tags: ajax, spring

How it's possible to send several string to spring? If I convert several Strings to the Array, I can send, but if I try to send several Strings it's not working. Send Array to Spring not good idea, becouse in Spring I will must use more code (split , new String, etc.)

```
function sendCustomerInfo() {

    var nameCustomerForSend = $("#NickNameCustomerForSend").val();
    var phoneCustomerForSend = $("#PhoneCustomerForSend").val();
    var emailCustomerForSend = $("#EmailCustomerForSend").val();
    var addressCustomerForSend = $("#descriptionCustomerForSend").val();

    console.log("Name: " + nameCustomerForSend + " Address: " + addressCustomerForSend + " Phone: " + phoneCustomerForSend
        + " Email: " + emailCustomerForSend);


    $.ajax({   
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        type: "POST", //это типа method
        data: {NickName:nameCustomerForSend, Phone:phoneCustomerForSend, Email:emailCustomerForSend,
            description:addressCustomerForSend},
        url: '/showAll/customerInfo',
        success: function (msg) {  
            window.location.href = "/showAll"
        }
    });
}
```

I receive: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()`
In Spring I try to receive:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/showAll/customerInfo", method = { RequestMethod.POST}
        , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ModelAndView showAllForCustomer(@RequestParam(value = "NickName")String name,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "Phone")String phone,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "description")String addressDelivery,
                                       @RequestParam(value = "Email")String email) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + name + " Phone: " + phone + " Address: " + addressDelivery + " Email: " + email);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    return modelAndView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RequestBody` with post and application/json type data
Create DTO having all parameter as you specified in showAllForCustomer
like

```
public ModelAndView showAllForCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDto dto){
    ............
}
```